# SQLAlchemy filter based on logic

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app which uses SQLAlchemy. For one of the endpoints `'/items'` I want to return a list of items.

So that's easy `ItemModel.query.all()` where `ItemModel` is the class representing items.

But say I want to allow url query string parameters e.g `'/items?type=book'`

If I hardcoded it would be simple with `TopicModel.query.filter_by(type=book).all()`

With multiple it could be `TopicModel.query.filter_by(type=book).filter_by(colour=yellow).all()`

But how could I efficiently generate that query so that it only filters by a parameter if the user gives a that parameter in the query string?

Should something like this work? If so would it perform multiple requests to the database (and therefore be slow and resource intensive)?

```
def get(self):
    type = request.args.get('type')
    color = request.args.get('color')
    size = request.args.get('size')

    query = ItemModel.query

    if type:
        query = query.filter_by(type=type)
    if color:
        query = query.filter_by(color=color)
    if size:
        query = query.filter_by(size=size)
    return {'items' : query.all() }
```

Comment: Your way of doing it should absolutely work. Be careful of the type of the arguments vs. the database. query.all() creates the SQL query and returns a list like item, it says in the documentation.

Comment: @MennoHölscher so to confirm: in my approach above it will only make one SQL query? Could you elaborate on what I need to be careful of with regards to type of arguments vs database? Thanks

Comment: Yes, only one query. As to typing: request arguments are strings. If in the database the field is integer, you need to pass the argument as an integer to the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out this.
You should not fetch all until you apply all conditions to the query.

```
def get(self):
    type = request.args.get('type')
    color = request.args.get('color')
    size = request.args.get('size')

    query_obj = ItemModel.query

    if type:
        query_obj = query_obj.filter_by(type=type)
    if color:
        query_obj = query_obj.filter_by(color=color)
    if size:
        query_obj = query_obj.filter_by(size=size)
    return {'items' : query_obj.all() }
```

Comment: can't you remove the .all() from each if statement to complete the objective of your rewrite? Your initial approach is stellar, don't run then filter rather filter then run, but the .all() in the 'if color:' section will return records...

Comment: I have updated it should work fine. @brddawg Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Here is your repaired code.

```
def get(self):
    type = request.args.get('type')
    color = request.args.get('color')
    size = request.args.get('size')

    query = ItemModel.query.all()

    if type:
        query = query.filter_by(type=type).all()
    if color:
        query = query.filter_by(color=color).all()
    if size:
        query = query.filter_by(size=size).all()
    return {'items' : query }
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if this would actually make 4 separate requests to the database?

Comment: No. its only one requests sent to database when you first ItemModel.query.all() called. After all you have to done only filters in some case in variable values.

Comment: Just tried it out but I get the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter_by'